# Scaling scatter plot in IPython Notebook

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm running an IPython Notebook:

```
$ ipython notebook --pylab inline
```

**Is it possible to scale plots or images which are inline?**

E.g. I have

```
pylab.xlabel("Label X")
pylab.ylabel("Label Y")
pylab.scatter(range(2,15,2), [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17], c="r")
```

and I want to have it bigger.

Sure, I can try to manually change parameters, e.g.

```
pylab.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
pylab.xlabel("Label X", fontsize = 20)
pylab.ylabel("Label Y", fontsize = 20)
pylab.scatter(range(2,15,2), [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17], c="r", s=100)
```

but it's neither convenient nor exact.

Comment: I don't think that you can modify by hand an inline figure, as you would do with one that pops up. You have to rerun the cell where you do the plotting. BTW: unless you have changed you `matplotlibrc` the default figure size is (8,6).

Comment: Have you found any solution to your problem? If so, please post your solution, and make sure the correct answer is accepted, so this question is marked as _solved_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python v2.7.4 running IPython v0.13 with matplotlib v1.2.0 32-bit on Windows 8, I get a "handle" in the lower right corner to manually resize (keep aspect ratio and resolution) the inline plot, at least when the `figure_format` in use is `'png'`. As for the other formats I'm not sure, but it appears that this behavior is not present when `'svg'` is used.

You can change the default `figure_format` by uncommenting the line starting with

`# c.InlineBackend.figure_format`

in the config-file `ipython_notebook_config.py` in your profile-folder for IPython, and set this parameter to whatever format you want to use when running the notebook, e.g. `'png'`.

If you want to change the default size of all inline plots, you can change the parameter `c.InlineBackend.rc` in the same config-file. If you e.g. want to set the `figsize` to `(12, 8)`, you simply uncomment the relevant line in the file, making it say

`c.InlineBackend.rc = {'figure.figsize': (12, 8)}`

This parameter can also change the default fontsize, dpi, etc.

Comment: I wan not interested in changing default options (rather - in IPython Notebook for a presentation). But I did install newer version (for another reason) and for Python 2.7  and IPython v0.13 (on Mac OS X) I can manually resize plots using mouse, so it's fine for me.